# DevExpress XtraReport currency thousand separator

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I have XtraReport with XtraLabel in detail band for display currency, ex: I have 2000000 and want to display it as 2.000.000, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting the FormatString property of 'Text` data binding as below.

```
xrLabel.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "{0:C}";
```

you can set refer [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify format string that you want to apply.

**References:**
[Formatting numeric values as Currency for an XrLabel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B208568)
[XRLabel - Setting FormatString during Report Generation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q435984)

Comment: It's worked, but with when I set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to my Culture, the number have extra decimal zero after comma, like "200.000,00".    I don't need the extra zero, so is it depend on the Culture, can I fix it without change the Culture?